# Do strict inequalities hold when taking limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm a bit confused on the following statement.

Suppose $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$ and that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ both exist.

In this case is it  true that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$.

Or is it true that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) < \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$.

I am not quite sure which one is true i think its the first one but I don't quite know why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(a,b)=(0,1)$, $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x$, then $f(x)<g(x)$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, strict inequalities are not preserved when taking limits. For instance, when $x>0$,
$$
\dfrac{x}{x+1} > \dfrac{x}{x+2}
$$

but

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x}{x+1} = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x}{x+2}.
$$

Or, to keep within the exact scope of the question, if you consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ defined on $(0,1)$, you'll see that even though $g(x) < f(x)$ you have that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)= \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=0$.

Comment: The OP wrote $x \to a$, presumably where $a$ is a real number.

Comment: @trivialmathisdifficult It is the same, if you consider Heine's definition of a limit. I'll switch to real functions anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify why it is the same? For example, $x + 1 > x$ for real $x$, and $\lim_{x \to 5} x + 1 > \lim_{x \to 5} x$, which is (I am assuming) the kind of example that OP is asking about holding.

Comment: @trivialmathisdifficult I'm not saying that it never happens... I'm just saying that, in general, you cannot assume that a strict inequality will hold after you take the limit. sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I see. OK, I agree. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: (+1) to counter the downvote. Even your first draft does not deserve a downvote. Geez...